# What's this show with a boy who has been recruited by missionaries?

Tags: isekai-no-seikishi

I remember the plot mostly but not the name of it. It begins with a boy that came from another world recruited by missionaries that have a mission of killing a princess before she gets to the "holy land".

- They all have mechas but the boys is more like a lizard mecha
- There are different races including Elves
- They go to a school at the holy land
- He wins a race against the Elves warrior and get their princesses hand in marriage
- The boy works as a jack-of-all-trades in the school
- It looks like an all girls school

Comment: I believe I saw it about a year or more ago and more info would be there where multi races including elves and one part I remember was the main boy character won a race against the fastest elven worrior and won the chance to thier princesses hand in marriage and there is magic and sometimes the boys mecha becomes surrounded in what is like a egg

Comment: When I saw it I believe it also just came out recently too, also the characters go to a school in the holy land and the main boy works there for odd jobs from everything and the school is an all girls academy

Comment: @anifan13: you should edit that into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it could be [Isekai no Seikishi Monogatari](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5781/Isekai_no_Seikishi_Monogatari) as there are multiple races, something about a princess, but I don't remember it that well.

His mecha looks like a lizard. He is the white one in this screenshot:

[image: mecha]

And if what you meant by egg is where the pilot is, then it could be this part of it:

[image: egg]

---

## [Isekai no Seikishi Monogatari](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5781/Isekai_no_Seikishi_Monogatari)

[image: cover]

## Synopsis

> Kenshi —half-brother of intergalactic hero Tenchi Masaki— has been summoned to the mysterious world of Geminar, and his only hope of returning to Earth is piloting a bio-mechanical weapon in a shocking assassination attempt! When the mission fails and Kenshi is captured, he discovers he's been lied to by the very culprits who transported him to this strange new world. Luckily, Princess Lashara kindly welcomes Kenshi and invites him to live amongst her followers. Now, caught up in a political whirlwind —and hotly pursued by Geminar's female population— Kenshi must find a way to get home while civil war erupts all around him!
>
> Source: FUNimation

Comment: @anifan13 glad that was what you were looking for it's a nice show ;) hope you like the anime & manga community as well.